# Shortcut for Navigating through Keyframes

Tags: keyframes, shortcut, grease-pencil

Is there a way to create a shortcut to navigate through keyframes?

The best I got is using the Arrow keys, but I have to have my mouse over the Dope sheet for them to function.

Can I do this without hovering over the Dope Sheet?

Thank you in advance

[image: The controls that I want to use with shortcuts]

Comment: You can use up and down arrow keys from the keyboard.

Comment: I see, I have to be in Blender Keymap mode for it to function. Is there a way to set this up for Industry compatible? The jump to keyframe option disappears when I go to Industry compatible.

Comment: Can't you assign your own shortcuts in this case?

Comment: Thanks to you I just realized how easy it was to assign shortcuts to any button on the interface, amazing. Thank you very much Lemon